# coldfusion search across site

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I'm trying to create a search box that searches across an entire coldfusion site and shows the search results. I've posted my HTML and JS code so far. I'm not that knowledgeable about search or coldfusion, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitSearch() {
var q = document.getElementById('q');
if (q.value.length == 0) {
    alert('Please enter a search word');
    }
else {
    var frmSearch = document.getElementById('frmSearch');
    }
}
</script>

    <div id="header-search">
    <form action="" method="post" id="frmSearch">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="Search">
    <input src="images/mag.png" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" class="btn" type="Button" onClick="submitSearch()" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without CF, just pure Javascript?

Comment: Hi, looks like you don't have much of a start there - what are you trying to search, static documents or the database? [or both?!] What you have so far is a form and some validation. Can we get more information?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it with pure javascript.  You can easily use solr integrated into ColdFusion.  You will need to use tags cfsearch and cfindex.

Comment: I'm trying to search across all CFM webpages for a search term in the search box.

Answer (score 3):

As posted by mbseid, check out `cfindex` and `cfsearch`.  You cannot use JS to search files that reside on the server.  The only way to do this is with `cfsearch`.  Read more about it here: [cfsearch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d02.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to use as the base for the search? If it's just database content used on several pages you'll probably have the most luck looking into Solr collections.

If it's the complete site you could just as well integrate a custom Google search. If the site content is public they'll probably have indexed the whole thing anyway. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I'm thinking of using Google search. Adding this line to the JS code that I have: window.location = 'http://www.google.com/...' I'm not sure what the URL should look like and how to attach the query.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

If the content is in actual ColdFusion pages, your simplest bet is to use a custom Google search.  If that isn't an option, then you would want to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
cfdirectory to get list of *.cfm files
cffile to read in each cfm file
if (content of file) contains (what you're looking for, e.g. #form.search#), store filename in an  array or a structure.
continue doing this through all files.
```

Then write a routine to output snippets, or a list of files or something with the content.

It's not elegant, but it'd do the job.

Comment: That makes sense. I want to do a Google search. I think if I add this line of JS it might work: window.location = 'http://www.google.com/' and add the query on to the end of the url. Not sure how the url should look like...